# decompose into a direct sum of irreps

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have got some problems such as:"Decompose the real representation $A$ of the group $G$ into a direct sum of irreps". Following problem  is one of them.

Let $\Phi$ be  the real representation of the cyclic group $C_4,$ such as $ \Phi(c)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 &-1\\0 & 1 & 0 \\1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$

Decompose $ \Phi$ into a direct sum of irreps.

I know real irrreps of the cyclic group $C_4. They are:

- trivial representation $T$
- representation $S$, such as $S(c)=S(c^3)=-1,$ $S(e)=S(c^2)$
- two-dimensional representation $A,$ such as  $A(c)=\begin{bmatrix}0 &-1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$
  I am not sure how to continue.
  Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: Use the character formulas....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping the second and third rows, and second and third columns changes your matrix to $\pmatrix{ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1} $. Can you now see how to decompose your representation?

Comment: Maybe $\pmatrix{ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1} =T \oplus A.$ Why Can I swap rows and columns?

Comment: Right. Because you can achieve it by conjugating by the permutation matrix corresponding to the permutation $(2,3)$.